# Duration when using CGAffineTransformTranslate

Tags: iphone, duration, cgaffinetransform

I am moving a view using CGAffineTransformTranslate and want to slow the move down. I tried using [UIView setAnimationDuration] but it does not do anything and the docs discourages it's use in iOS 4.0 and later.

```
whatIfToolBar.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(whatIfToolBar.transform,0.0, -whatIfToolBar.frame.size.height);
```

What is the proper way to set the duration?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 4):

I should have read further before asking my question...

[UIView setAnimationDuration] only works when using Begin/Commit methods and must be called between calls to begin and commit animations and before changing any animatable properties of the view.

For iOS 4 or later applications you should use block-based methods for animation. Duration is set when calling a block method. See the [Animations section of the View Programming Guide for iOS"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html).

If you application will be run in iOS 3.2 and earlier you must use Begin/Commit methods.

In my case I used Begin/Commit methods...

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"whatIfToolBar" context:whatIfToolBar];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
whatIfToolBar.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity,0.0, - whatIfToolBar.frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

If I were to use block-based methods it would look like this...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
          animations:^{
               whatIfToolBar.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity,0.0, -whatIfToolBar.frame.size.height);

          }
];
```

John

Comment: Still relevant in 2017 in iOS 10. (Begin/Commit methods)